# Creating a note taking app using JQuery mobile and phone gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, web-applications, cordova

I have an app i'm developing with JQ Mobile and PhoneGap. Within this app, i want to include a '**Notes Taking**' page and it has to do the following.

1. Make new notes and save them locally.
2. Recall them whenever i need to,
3. Edit them and delete them

i could not find a good example to follow, i tried this:

http://tutorialzine.com/2012/09/simple-note-taking-app-ajax/

but he lost me at the index php and how to implement that, i also tried this example:

http://miamicoder.com/2011/building-a-jquery-mobile-application-part-1/

but its so complex i got lost in all the code.

I'm a beginner at programming and my JavaScript is very very poor and i have no idea where to start and what kind of code is involved in making this part of the app.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to take some basic JS courses and become familiar with it. Us writing your code for you won't be beneficial to us or you.

Comment: You have picked up a task that's quite advanced for a novice level JavaScript programmer. I'd follow @tymeJV's advice and learn JS prior to going into jQuery Mobile, let alone mobile-specific stuff in JS (including PhoneGap's database layers, local storage etc.). There's a LOT to study up before you can even start designing such an application I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i understand. could you at least speak on what is involved in creating such an app in terms of JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first site (http://tutorialzine.com/2012/09/simple-note-taking-app-ajax/) will not work for you as the examples are embedding PHP into the html and that is not acceptable with phonegap apps.

Your second site is making it way more complicated than it needs to be for your limited scope.

Not going to do this for you but I will give you some advice and places to look.

1. Draw out what you want the user interface to look like and create that html
2. Create a load and save function in javascript to... well... load and save your notes. Take a look at the below references:

   [This](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) will show you how to interact with the local database and store and retrieve info. Always a good thing to read the documentation.

   [This](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) is a great resource for help all sorts of stuff. In this case, with SQL queries.
3. Test, test, test. With the above, you will be able to figure it out if you put your mind to it. Come back here and post specific questions with code samples of what you have tried if you get stuck.